# ANSI escape color codes don't work in Python terminal

Tags: python, colors

Ill tried to "colorize" my terminal but I always fail!
In Atom Terminal it works *perfectly*, like really, and in Python console I get this output
`←[95mColored Text`. That's strange, maybe you guys have a idea.

My code

```
class color:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    CYAN = '\033[96m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

choose= input(color.HEADER + "Colored Text")
```

Comment: It has to do with whether the output destination support ANSI escape codes. Some do and some don't. For example the Windows `cmd` command-line "terminal" does not. (There are says to add the capability to understand them to it though).

Comment: Sure it does, but it depends on your OS and terminal settings. If on windows, you should ensure your terminal supports ANSI escape sequences, and preferably also have `VT` (Virtual Terminal)  enabled. Latest powershell support 24-bit *TRUECOLOR* and you should probably also set your **`TERM`** environment variable to `xterm-256color`. You can also try a REPL hack, that sometimes has worked on older Python versions: `import os; os.system('')`. Try to enable VT with: 
`sp HKCU:\Console VirtualTerminalLevel -Type DWORD 1`, but this may need to be done properly using `ConinMode.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Note all terminals or operating systems support the same [ANSI escape codes here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/user-guide/materials/ansi-escape-codes/) for colors, and not all languages support `\033[` as the Control Sequence Introducer (CSI). Have you tried using the `\x1b[`, `\u001b[` or `\u1b[` variations of the CSI?

Also, it's recommend to use `\033[0m` every time you want to revert back to the default terminal text style. Otherwise, any color or styling may spill over and into other terminal messages. Just updating your example:

```py
class color:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OFF = '\033[0m'

choose = input(color.HEADER + "Colored Text" + color.OFF)
```

But why code everything from scratch? Several Python packages can solve your problem. In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) package. [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) is lightweight and less verbose. Simply install the package with `pip install colorist` and refer to the [background color options](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/reference/background-colors/mixed/).

Other options for foreground colors:

```py
from colorist import red

red("some text in red color")
```

[image: some text in red color]

Sometimes you may want a little more control over the terminal style, so you can also do this:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"Only {Color.CYAN}this part{Color.OFF} is in colour")
```

[image: 5]

Comment: Python supports `\033[` just fine; the problem is with the OP's terminal, not how they are defining the ANSI escape codes.

Comment: All the character sequences you listed are just different ways of defining the exact same value.  Using one over the other won't make any difference.

Comment: It may work fine with `\033[0m`. I don't doubt it, and it's probably the option supported by most terminals and languages. Yet, it isn't entirely correct that all CSI options are equal. Find a reference here: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2020/03/28/terminal-colors.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this once. you would want to use u""

```py
class color:
    HEADER = u'\033[95m'
    BLUE = u'\033[94m'
    CYAN = u'\033[96m'
    GREEN = u'\033[92m'
    WARNING = u'\033[93m'
    FAIL = u'\033[91m'
    ENDC = u'\033[0m'
    BOLD = u'\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = u'\033[4m'
choose = input(color.HEADER + "Colored Text")
```

Comment: That will make absolutely no difference, not even in Python 2.